# Creating multiple TextInput fields in for loop

Tags: actionscript-3, loops, for-loop, mxml

I need to loop through an array and for each element create a textfield. My problem is how to create a new identifier for each new TextInput

this is my code;

```
var count:Number = 0;
for (var i:String in columnsData)
{
var myTI:TextInput = new TextInput();
myTI.width = 70;
myTI.height = 25;
myTI.text = columnsData[i];
myTI.name = "myTI" + count;
addChild(myTI);
count++;    
   }
```

all this does however is overwrite the previously created TextInput field, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var count:uint = 0,
    textInputs:Array /* of TextInputs */ = [];
for(var i:String in columnsData){
    textInputs[count] = new TextInput();
    // Customize textInput[count] instead of myTI
    addChild(textInputs[count]);
    count++;
}
```

Outside of this loop, you should be able to look inside the `textInputs` array for references to each of your new TextInputs. Note that, inside the loop, you probably want to change the x/y coordinates for each TextInput so they don't overlap.